# Firestore Transactions do not work

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I found [some issue thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14655) with people also not being able to complete transactions, but it does not even provide *solutions*.

### Problem

Suddenly, my [transactions crashes](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18870) when using `transaction.get`.

```
runTransaction(
  (Transaction transaction) async {
    await transaction.get(documentReference); // "Timed out waiting for Task"
  }
```

The *`PlatformException`* does also not really help me because it crashes in `platform_channel`...

```
E/flutter (16297): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (16297): PlatformException(Error performing transaction, Timed out waiting for Task, null)
E/flutter (16297): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:547:7)
E/flutter (16297): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:279:18)
E/flutter (16297): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16297): #2      Firestore.runTransaction (file:///G:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.7.3/lib/src/firestore.dart:115:10)
// here comes another <asynchronous suspension> followed by my code
```

This comes from *Android*.

Comment: are you trying to get a nonexistent document? i used to have that problem because i was trying to get a nonexistent document

Comment: @DavidHMoreno No, my *document **exists***. The `PlatformException` is also thrown *immediately*, i.e. no reach out to the server.

Comment: You can also upvote https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18870

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having has since been fixed by the `cloud_firestore` team.

If you are still experiencing a similar issue, you should either ask a question here on StackOverflow or [create an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=BUG.md&title=).

Answer (score 0):

This Error comes sometimes because:

- don't debug the transaction while it's running, so put the breakpoint in a proper line before or after.

---

Another errors come because you don't :

- do all get calls first, then your write or update comes.

  as Firestore document said:

  "*Read operations must come before write operations.*"

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions

Answer (score 0):

> Note: You can also make atomic changes to data using transactions.
>   While this is a bit heavy-handed for incrementing a vote total, it is
>   the right approach for more complex changes. Here is what a
>   transaction that updated the votes count might look like.

```
onTap: () => Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {

final freshSnapshot = await transaction.get(record.reference);

final fresh = Record.fromSnapshot(freshSnapshot);

await transaction

.update(record.reference, {'votes': fresh.votes + 1});

}),
```

> How does this work? By wrapping the read and write operations in one
>   transaction, you're telling Cloud Firestore to only commit a change if
>   there was no external change to the underlying data while the
>   transaction was running. If two users aren't concurrently voting on
>   that particular name, the transaction runs exactly once. But if the
>   number of votes changes between the transaction.get(...) and the
>   transaction.update(...) calls, the current run isn't committed, and
>   the transaction is retried. After 5 failed retries, the transaction
>   fails.

**Source**
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/index.html#10

Answer (score -1):

This works without any problems:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  final FirebaseApp app = await FirebaseApp.configure(
    name: 'yourappname',
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
      googleAppID: 'yourgoogleid',
      gcmSenderID: 'yourgmssenderid',
      apiKey: 'yourapikey',
      projectID: 'yourprojectid',
    ),
  );
  final Firestore firestore = Firestore(app: app);
  await firestore.settings(
  timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled: true,
  persistenceEnabled: true,
  sslEnabled: true
  );

  runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: 'Firestore Example', home: MyHomePage(firestore: firestore)));
}

class MessageList extends StatelessWidget {
  MessageList({this.firestore});

  final Firestore firestore;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
        final int messageCount = snapshot.data.documents.length;
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: messageCount,
          itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
            final DocumentSnapshot document = snapshot.data.documents[index];
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(document['message'] ?? '<No message retrieved>'),
              subtitle: Text('Message ${index + 1} of $messageCount'),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({this.firestore});
  final Firestore firestore;
  CollectionReference get messages => firestore.collection('messages');

  Future<void> _addMessage() async {
final DocumentReference postRef = firestore.document('posts/123');
firestore.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async {
  DocumentSnapshot postSnapshot = await tx.get(postRef);
  if (postSnapshot.exists) {
    await tx.update(postRef, <String, dynamic>{'likesCount': postSnapshot.data['likesCount'] + 1});
  }
});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Firestore Example'),
      ),
      body: MessageList(firestore: firestore),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _addMessage,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```