# Flutter/cloud-firestore "Task is already complete" Exception

Tags: android, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I'm writing an app using Flutter and i have to make a transaction using the `Firestore.instance.runTransaction(Transaction tx)` method.
In my Transaction object (or method) i have to update some data using the document reference.

```
_firestore.runTransaction((Transaction x) async {
  await x.update(Aref, {'data': itemA - y});
  await x.update(Bref, {'data': itemB + y});
})
```

When the code is running  it throw an exception (Here the console log):

> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(32612): Failed to handle method call result
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(32612): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is already complete
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(32612):     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Unknown Source:8)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(32612):     at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.zzdr(Unknown Source:8)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(32612):     at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.setResult(Unknown Source:3)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(32612):     at com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Unknown Source:2)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(32612):     at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$3$1.success(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:283)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(32612):     at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingResultHandler.reply(MethodChannel.java:169)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(32612):     at io.flutter.view.FlutterNativeView.handlePlatformMessageResponse(FlutterNativeView.java:187)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(32612):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(32612):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(32612):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)

Comment: Having the same issue. I think that I filed an issue and asked a question here at some point already some time ago, but I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: It is a similar issue I encountered, although I am also encountering your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51051730/firestore-transactions-do-not-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens when there are multiple call to the firestore api concurrently, you have to nest each funcion inside the 
"whenComplete(() {}" method of the previous function.
This is the **wrong** code :

```
g.f.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      DocumentSnapshot snap =
          await transaction.get(/my code);

      await transaction.update(/my code).whenComplete(() {});
    });


g.f.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      DocumentSnapshot freshSnap =
              await transaction.get(/my code));

      await transaction.update(/my code).whenComplete(() {});
});  //here is the problem!! I'have to nest this inside "whenComplete(() {})
```

this is the error:

> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 5337): Failed to
>   handle method call result
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 5337):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is already complete

**this is right code**

```
g.f.runTransaction((transaction) async {
  DocumentSnapshot snap =
      await transaction.get(/my code);

  await transaction.update(/my code).whenComplete(() {
    g.f.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      DocumentSnapshot freshSnap =
          await transaction.get(/my code);

      await transaction.update(/my code);
    }).whenComplete(() {});
  });
});
```

Comment: This was definitely not the cause of the issue (for me). Because I am still having the issue and I am not using your "wrong code".

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot check if there is another call to firestore concurrently like "document ().update ()" or something similar

Comment: No, there is not. What are you basing this knowledge on? I do not see a reason for concurrent operations not working and it is, moreover, not easy to run these operations concurrently because they do not take a long time to execute.

Comment: I got the same error and worked for me, maybe there are other reason for the same error

Comment: There is no reason to make concurrent calls of `whenComplete`, it simply ruins the meaning of `runTransaction`, however it might worked for you cause there is a bug in `runTransaction` as of now, so these concurrent calls are just short time solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try this. Hope it Helps 
[FIrestore Transaction Handler](https://github.com/thevzurd/Firestore-Transaction-Handler)

## Firestore-Transaction-Handler

This is a subroutine to help handle the failing transaction issue when using `runTransaction` function in `cloud_firestore` pub for `Flutter`

## The Problem

This code is a solution to errors with cloud_firestore package for Flutter for the following errors 
1.  `PlatformException(Error performing Transaction#get, Transaction has already completed., null)`
2.  `DoTransaction failed: Document version changed between two reads.`

From my experience, I realized that the issue occurs when I try to update a record which was only just created.
For some reason the `tx.get()` (see the example for `runTransaction` in https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) is unable to get the record that was just created and the update operation fails. 
I found that if we wait for a bit and try again, we will be able to get the record and update it. 
To make things easy, I have created a function that does the update and run transaction for you.

## The Solution

Here is an example :

```
     await fcmTransactionHandler(
      postRef: postRef, //  This is your DocumentReference that you want to update
      key: 'myfield', // This is the field that you want to update
      validationFunction: updateMyField, // This is a function that allows you to check 
      // some condition in the record you 'get' before updating
 );
```

`validationFunction` takes a dynamic value (value of the field you want to update) as input and gives the `{}` value that you will update in the record.
For example, if I want to update a field `myfield` if it is say `true`, then I will create a function `updateMyField` as follows

```
Map<String, dynamic> updateMyField({dynamic value}) {
    return  value ? <String, dynamic>{'myfield': true} : <String, dynamic>{'myfield': value};
  }
```

Then this function is passed to `validationFunction`.
Why is it designed like this ? 
As you have seen, we are trying to get the record after a while and then update it. What if the record has been updated by someone else in between ?
In that case, we have to validate the data we get when the record is available for us, to prevent any incorrect updates.
`validationFunction` helps us do that.